# Find the domain of the function $f(x) =\frac{1}{\log_{x-1}\frac{x+3}{x-8}}$

Tags: functions

"How would I find the domain of this function?
$$f(x) =\frac{1}{\log_{x-1}\frac{x+3}{x-8}}$$

This is what I done so far: $$\log_{x-1}\frac{x+3}{x-8} \neq 0$$
$$$$
$$\frac{x+3}{x-8} \neq (x-1)^0$$
$$$$
$$\frac{x+3}{x-8} \neq 1$$
$$$$
$$\frac{x+3}{x-8} - 1 \neq 0 \space\space\space\space/\cdot(x-8)$$
$$$$
$$x+3-x+8 \neq 0$$
$$$$
$$11 \neq 0$$

What does it gives me?
How do I continue?

And can I write $"\neq"$ every step or should I write $"="$ ?

Comment: The base of the logarithm must be positive and not $1$.

Comment: Recall that $\log_a b=\dfrac{\log b}{\log a}$, where the logarithms in the right-hand side are in whatever (fixed) base you want.

Comment: @user170231 I know, but what about the argument?

Comment: @egreg What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, log is defined for positive real numbers

Given  $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\log_{x-1}\frac{x+3}{x-8}}$$

$$=\frac{\log(x-1)}{\log \frac{x+3}{x-8}}$$

Now, we have following inequalities

1. $$x-1>0\iff x>1$$
2. $$\frac{x+3}{x-8}>0$$$$(x+3)(x-8)>0\iff  x<-3\ \text{or}\ \ x>8$$

Taking both (1) & (2) solutions on the number line, one gets the solution of given inequality $$\color{red}{x>8}$$

Comment: $y=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}=x$?!

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot  Why didn't you include $x\neq 2$ as a third condition?

Comment: Alright, you should know the condition that logarithm is defined for positive real numbers is governing the condition itself. hence, you needn't to show $x\neq 2$

Answer (score 2):

You're missing several conditions. I'd start from the inner part: in order for
$$
\log_{x-1}\frac{x+3}{x-8}=\frac{\ln\dfrac{x+3}{x-8}}{\ln(x-1)}
$$
to exist, we need
$$
\frac{x+3}{x-8}>0 \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
x-1>0\tag{2}
$$
just for the existence of the logarithms. Then we must also have
$$
\ln(x-1)\ne0\tag{3}
$$
and
$$
\ln\frac{x+3}{x-8}\ne0\tag{4}
$$
because otherwise we can't take the inverse.

Condition $(1)$ is “$x<-3$ or $x>8$”; condition $(2)$ is $x>1$; condition $(3)$ is $x\ne2$; condition $(4)$ is $x+3\ne x-8$ (which is true).

Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

$y=log ^u _{v}$ then $u>0$ & $a>0$ and $a\neq 1$ thus $\log_{x-1}\frac{x+3}{x-8}$

1) $x-1>0$ so $x>1$

2) $\frac{x+3}{x-8}>0$ so $x<-3$ or $x>8$

3)$x-1\neq 1$ so $x\neq 2$

add this $\frac{x+3}{x-8}\neq 1$

Answer (score 0):

At first, note that

$$\log_{x-1} \frac{x+3}{x-8} = \frac{\log\frac{x+3}{x-8}}{\log (x-1)}$$

Thus

$$f(x) = \frac{\log (x-1)}{\log \frac{x+3}{x-8}}$$

So we get the conditions

\begin{align*}
x-1 &> 0 \qquad (1)\\
x-8 &\neq 0 \qquad (2)\\
\frac{x+3}{x-8} &> 0 \qquad (3)\\
\log \frac{x+3}{x-8} &\neq 0 \qquad (4)
\end{align*}

Out of $(1)$ we get $x > 1$, out of $(3)$ we get, since $x > 1$ at least, that $x > 8$, otherwise the denominator and hence the whole fracture gets negative. We find no further restrictions, hence

$$f: (8,\infty) \to \Bbb R$$

Comment: Yes, hence conditions $(1)$ and $(3)$.